# How can I output a list from TensorFlow Dataset map function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I need examples in my dataset to be in the format `([feature_1, feature_2,...], labels)` as I'm using [Keras.Model.fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator). To do this, I'm going to read from `.tfrecord`s:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tf_records)
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parser, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
...
```

However, I'm having difficulty with the `map_func`:

```
def parser(record, training=True):
    context_features = {
        "labels": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)
    }

    sequence_features = {
        "feature_1": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
        "feature_2": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string)
    }

    context_parse, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(record, context_features, sequence_features)

    X_feature_1 = tf.decode_raw(sequence_parsed["feature_1"], tf.uint8)
    X_feature_2 = tf.decode_raw(sequence_parsed["feature_2"], tf.uint8)
    y = tf.sparse_to_dense(context_parse["labels"].values, [3862], 1)

    return ([X_feature_1, X_feature_2], y)
```

If I try to use the list to hold `[X_feature_1, X_feature_2]` as above, I end up getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

How can I pass along a tuple that contains a list?

**Update (Workaround solution):**

So, the code in the question is part of a generator. I realized that since the generator just runs a tensorflow graph (hope the terminology is correct, I'm still new to this), I can do my conversion at the end instead:

```
 feature_1, feature_2, y = sess.run(next_el)
 yield [feature_1, feature_2], y
```

Whilst this works, I still which I could do this in the map function.

Comment: MAP: function mapping a nested structure of tensors (having shapes and types defined by self.output_shapes and self.output_types) to another nested structure of tensors. the problem is you are return a list of tensor whereas maps a nested list of tensors

Comment: i think the best way would be to retun them x_features,x_features_2, y and stack them in feed dict but since i don't know how your model is structured...i can't guess

Comment: I thought about stacking but that involves having matching dimensions. I've found a workaround that works. I've posted it in an update to the question.

Comment: iMo you should do it after the session.run(next_elem) and again since I can't see the code, I won't be able to guess how to pass the input to the model,in tensorflow,you usually define placeholder whereas in keras you pass the input directly to the model,in tensorflow, you could define a placeholder with the dimensions of x1,x2 and pass them via feed dict as numpy val since next_el evaluate the tensors to numpy objs

Comment: have you tried changing the inner list to a tuple?

Comment: Sorry, missed your reply. The problem with that is that Keras expects it as a list, so even if that worked (IIRC it would complain about the tuple not having some shape property), I would still have to reformat it in the `yield` snippet in my update above. Looks like said workaround is the cleanest way around this.